# Add-Ins Category missing from Customize / Commands / Categories - Can't Use Add-Ins?

Tags: arcobjects, add-in, visual-studio

I've created a Add-In button that says "Hello World" when clicked.
I want to add button to a toolbar.

I've tried creating my own "Category" in the Add-In wizard, no success.
I've also accepted the default "Category" called "Add-Ins", no success.

The Add-In appears to load but is not assigned to a visible "Category".
So, I can't use it.

I've run the Add-In via Visual Studio, Installed via the ESRI ArcGIS Add-In Installation Utility, and loaded the file via the Customize / Customize Mode / Commands.

What is the issue?
Do I need to enable Add-Ins or turn on an extension?

Comment: Please post the Config.esriaddinx contents. It might make it easier figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the following code in your Config.esriaddinx:

```
  <AddIn language="CLR" library="Your_addin.dll" namespace="Your_addin">
    <ArcMap>
      <Commands>
        <Button id="Your_addin_Button" class="LaunchButton" message="" caption="Button" tip="" category="Add-In Controls" image="Images\Search.png" />
      </Commands>
      <Toolbars>
        <Toolbar id="Your_YourToolbar" caption="YourToolbar">
          <Items>
            <Button refID="Your_addin_Button" />
          </Items>
        </Toolbar>
      </Toolbars>
    </ArcMap>
  </AddIn>
```